# Moving Balsamiq Mockups from Web to Desktop App

Tags: wireframe, mockups, mockup-tool, balsamiq

How do I export Balsamiq mockups from the demo web app to the desktop app using the 'Export Mockup XML' option. If I try to save the resulting XML to a BMML or BMRL file the desktop app refuses to open them. Is there a simple way to get this to work? Is there a way to import all mockups at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there and sorry for the hassle.

You can move your mockups from myBalsamiq to Mockups 3 for Desktop by following these steps:

- First, [download your project(s) from the myBalsamiq Home Page](https://docs.balsamiq.com/mybalsamiq/home/#uploading-and-downloading-projects)
- Then, you can [import the related ZIP file in the Desktop version](https://docs.balsamiq.com/desktop/importing/#importing-mockups-from-a-previous-version-bmml-files) via "Project > Import > Project from BMMLs ZIP"

Hope this helps! Please let us know if you need anything else (support@balsamiq.com).

-Virgin from Balsamiq